# Merge two videos with ffmpeg Without BAT file (C#)

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ProcessStartInfo info1 = new ProcessStartInfo("app.bat"); 

app.bat
```

The app.bat file consists of the following command. It is for windows only.

```
copy e:\cars1.mpg /b + e:\cars2.mpg /b e:\output.mpg /b
```

How to using this code without .BAT file directly or another ffmpeg command?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't need FFmpeg for this if this batch file is working for you.  Just `cat` the files together.

Comment: ffmpeg -i "concat:tg1.mp4\|tg2.mp4" WOOF.mp4     // can't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Merge two videos without re-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371422/how-to-merge-two-videos-without-re-encoding)