# Concatenate two files while keeping the duration the same as the two files separately

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

When I calculate the duration of each individual file I want to concatenate I get 10.24 for both. So I figured when I concatenate the two files I would get a duration of file A plus file B or 10.24 + 10.24 giving me a total duration of 20.48 for the combined file. But no matter what command I use to concentrate I cannot get the same duration. Am I doing something wrong?

```
ffprobe -i "audioA.mp3" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
10.24
```

```
ffprobe -i "audioB.mp3" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
10.24
```

Which makes a total of 10.24 + 10.24 = **20.48 seconds**

But when I concatenate the files I get a different duration. Here are my different tries.

**Try 1**

```
FFMPEG -y -i 'concat:audioA.mp3|audioB.mp3' -map 0:a -codec:a copy -map_metadata -1 output.mp3
ffprobe -i "output.mp3" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
20.610612
```

**Try 2**

```
FFMPEG -y -i audioA.mp3 -i audioB.mp3 -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 output.mp3
ffprobe -i "output.mp3" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0
20.453878
```

**Try 3**

```
FFMPEG -y -i 'concat:audioA.mp3|audioB.mp3' output.mp3
ffprobe -i "output.mp3" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
20.506122
```

- Is there a command to use to concatenate that will output a file with
  the same duration?
- Is there a way to do that without reencoding?
- What makes the durations different in the combined files above?

Comment: From my experience with FFmpeg, it's complicated to achieve a precise duration. I have seen the duration of my outputs changing depending on the format, the codec and the filters used (obivously).
If you want to concatenate them without reencoding, you have information [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371422/how-to-merge-two-videos-without-re-encoding)

Comment: Yea the thing is both the files are the same exact file. So it's the same codec bitrate - everything is the exact same. Not sure why the duration would be different when put together. And the calculated durations are always consistent.

Comment: Did you manage to keep the same duration? I am interested in the solution

Comment: I did not unfortunately :/